# Merging and generalising polygon data with ogr2ogr and SQL

Tags: sql, ogr2ogr

I have some building data that is already generalised to blocks of buildings rather than individual buildings, and I want to create another set of data from it that is generalised again to urban areas.

Here's a sample of what I have:

[image: Original data, building generalised to blocks]

You may be able to make out that there are spaces between the blocks, which account for roads/parks/etc. So the polygons I have are disconnected, so a simple merge/dissolve won't do quite what I want.

What I want to end up with is something like this (excuse the poor Photoshop skills):

[image: Buildings generalised to urban areas]

Basically, I want to end up with polygons like the ones I have crudely drawn in black. So the buildings data is generalised and merged into urban areas where the buildings are pretty dense. I don't mind if buildings in sparse areas are either drawn as-is or ignored entirely, either is fine (but the latter is preferable).

I am using ogr2ogr to preprocess all of my data along with the `-sql` flag to filter my data and create new types (for example, I've processed point data representing roundabouts into polygon data, removed unwanted metadata etc), so if I can achieve my goals using SQL rather than QGIS that would be preferable.

Any ideas?